# Reindex vs Update Api in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm wondering if there's any real difference between using ES's Reindex Api vs the Update Api (besides docs being indexed into a new index in the Reindex case).

My particular use case is I just want to script some updates to a few fields in all my docs in particular indexes. For me, it would be advantageous to not have new indexes.

Answer (score 1):

If your use-case is just updating a few fields in the existing documents then you should go with update API.

Reindex API, is useful when you want to create a new index from old(mainly used with Alias API) to provide the ZDT.